# Will Azrael himself get the souls of animals? (To die)

Tags: malaikah, animals, soul

As probably many of you know, Azrael (عزرائیل) has been appointed as the responsible angel who gets the souls of humans at the time of their life (when dying). But I was wondering if he (Azrael) is the responsible of getting the souls of animals as well? Or factually, animals will be died by another way?

*Note: Please, present related Qur'anic verses or hadith (tradition) for your answers as much as possible.*

Comment: I don't want to post this as an answer, but check out this link [here](https://islamqa.info/en/119652)

Comment: On a side note, there is not even a single verse or authentic hadith that tells us the name of the Angel of Death. That Angel has been referred to as ["The Angel of Death"](http://quran.com/32/11)

Comment: Uh-huh, admirable point. Meanwhile, the following link looked helpful. God bless you.

Comment: So if there is answer of this questin which you have found post it and accept it.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal, I made researched, and found and prepared an answer, as you made me eager to do more research ... / Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a clear direct hadith/narration regarding this issue, but there can be inferred of some/several hadiths that:

Apparently, Azrael gets the souls of animals.
As a relevant narration which can confirm it, is that:

> I have no power of doing anything without the permission of Allah,
> even to get the soul of the flight (mosquito).

**Ref.:**

[www.welayatnet.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20161022081812/http://www.welayatnet.com:80/fa/news/43827)